# how to extract BIC from several regression results by apply function in r

Tags: r, class, apply

I already have several regression results, e.g. `fit1, fit2, fit3`.
And I want to extract BIC from the regression result by using `apply` function.

Question is, when I code as follow:

```
fitresult = cbind(fit1, fit2, fit3)
BIC = apply(fitresult, 2, BIC)
```

It shows error:

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : no applicable method for 'logLik'
applied to an object of class "list"
```

I checked and find `class(fitresult[1]) = 'list'` and `loglik` cannot apply on 'list' class. I think this error means I cannot use `BIC(fitresult[1])` because `fitresult[1]` is not a fit result object.

So how can I use apply function to make each component in `fitresult` applied by `apply` function? By changing the `class` of each component?

Comment: Please review how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8386140) to help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** The `cbind` operation strips the model class (for example, class is `lm` if the model object was created with the `lm` function) from the model objects, but `BIC` expects an object with a model class (like `lm` or `glm`). Instead, do `lapply(list(fit1, fit2, fit3), BIC)` and `BIC` will work.

---

Assuming `fit1`, `fit2`, and `fit3` are objects that resulted from running a modeling function (like `lm` or `glm`), then these are objects are lists containing the model output (for example, run `str(fit1)`.

`BIC` is expecting a model object (for example, if the model was created with `lm`, the output object would be a list of class `lm`). However, the output of `cbind(fit1, fit2, fit3)` has class `matrix`, and each column contains all the sub-list elements from a given model object (for example, type `fitresult`, `class(fitresult)`, `fitresult[1, ]`, and `fitresult[2, ]` in the console and see what happens). However, these columns of `fitresult` no longer have the model class `lm` attached to them, so BIC doesn't know how to operate on them. For example, if you used `lm` to create the model then `class(fit1)` would return `lm`. But after the `cbind` operation. note that `class(fitresult[ ,1])` returns `list`.

Instead, put these model objects into a list and use `lapply` to run `BIC` on each model object:

```
lapply(list(fit1, fit2, fit3), BIC)
```

The output should be a list where each element is the BIC from a given model. If you want the output as a vector, you can do:

```
sapply(list(fit1, fit2, fit3), BIC)
```

Comment: Or vapply: `vapply(list(fit1, fit2, fit3), BIC, numeric(1))`